# Es posible eliminar un caracter dada alguna condicional en R?

Tags: r

Necesito ayuda para limpiar una base de datos en R.

Necesito quitar un punto que se encuentra en el inicio de algunas lineas, estoy utilizando R y la **formula `sub("^.","", x)`** el problema es que utilizando esta formula me elimina la 1era linea de toda mi base, es possible usar algun condicional?

**ejemplo: Original database**

```
.2199.00
 99,90
 18,013
.123.00`
```

**Lo que necesito**

```
 2199.00
 99,90
 18,013
 123.00`
```

**utilizando `sub("^.","", x)`**

```
 2199.00
 9,90
 8,013
 23.00`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En expresiones regulares el punto es un carácter reservado (ie, significa algo más que el punto como carácter). Para detercar el punto debes *escapear* el carácter con `"\\"`. Ve el ejemplo.

```r
x <- c(".2199.00", "99,90", "18,013", ".123.00")
x
#> [1] ".2199.00" "99,90"    "18,013"   ".123.00"

gsub("^.", "", x)
#> [1] "2199.00" "9,90"    "8,013"   "123.00"

gsub(".", "", x)
#> [1] "" "" "" ""

gsub("^\\.", "", x)
#> [1] "2199.00" "99,90"   "18,013"  "123.00"
```

En particular `"."` *matchea* cualquier carácter, por eso en el segundo ejemplo reemplaza todo.